# Can't make block and model rewrite working

Tags: module, ce-1.9.0.1, overrides

I am getting mental break because I can't make my custom module which should rewrite 2 blocks and 1 model work.
My module is loaded - I checked in admin panel `System->Configuration->Advanced` but Magento still reads core files.
Overmore, I am trying to rewrite reviews form so when I am in admin panel watching reviews and make intentional mistake in name of class in `Acme_Reviewed_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form` I get blank screen so it looks like it is reading my blocks and models. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere which I can't find.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Acme_Reviewed>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Acme_Reviewed>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <reviewed>
            <class>Acme_Reviewed_Model</class>
        </reviewed>
        <review>
            <rewrite>
                <resource_review>Acme_Reviewed_Model_Resource_Review</resource_review>
            </rewrite>
        </review>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <reviewed>
            <class>Acme_Reviewed_Block</class>
        </reviewed>
        <ajaxreviews>
            <rewrite>
                <reviews>Acme_Reviewed_Block_Reviews</reviews>
            </rewrite>
        </ajaxreviews>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <review_edit_form>Acme_Reviewed_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Acme_Reviewed.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Acme_Reviewed>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Adminhtml />
            <Mage_Review />
            <Magpleasure_Ajaxreviews />
        </depends>
    </Acme_Reviewed>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I try to override:

```
Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review.php
Magpleasure/Ajaxreviews/Block/Reviews.php
Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

With my files:

```
Acme/Reviewed/Model/Resource/Review.php
Acme/Reviewed/Block/Reviews.php
Acme/Reviewed/Block/Adminhtml/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

**Acme/Reviewed/Model/Resource/Review.php**

```
<?php

class Acme_Reviewed_Model_Resource_Review extends Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review
{
    protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        /**
         * save detail
         */
        Mage::log(var_export($object->getGemail(), TRUE), null, 'furoris.log');
        $detail = array(
            'title'     => $object->getTitle(),
            'detail'    => $object->getDetail(),
            'nickname'  => $object->getNickname(),
            'gemail' => $object->getGemail(),
        );
        $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->_reviewDetailTable, 'detail_id')
            ->where('review_id = :review_id');
        $detailId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, array(':review_id' => $object->getId()));

        if ($detailId) {
            $condition = array("detail_id = ?" => $detailId);
            Mage::log("a", null, 'furoris.log');
            $adapter->update($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail, $condition);
            Mage::log("b", null, 'furoris.log');
        } else {
            Mage::log($this->_reviewDetailTable, null, 'furoris.log');
            $detail['store_id']   = $object->getStoreId();
            $detail['customer_id']= $object->getCustomerId();
            $detail['review_id']  = $object->getId();
            $detail['gemail'] = $object->getGemail();
            $adapter->insert($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail);
        }


        /**
         * save stores
         */
        $stores = $object->getStores();
        if (!empty($stores)) {
            $condition = array('review_id = ?' => $object->getId());
            $adapter->delete($this->_reviewStoreTable, $condition);

            $insertedStoreIds = array();
            foreach ($stores as $storeId) {
                if (in_array($storeId, $insertedStoreIds)) {
                    continue;
                }

                $insertedStoreIds[] = $storeId;
                $storeInsert = array(
                    'store_id' => $storeId,
                    'review_id'=> $object->getId()
                );
                $adapter->insert($this->_reviewStoreTable, $storeInsert);
            }
        }

        // reaggregate ratings, that depend on this review
        $this->_aggregateRatings(
            $this->_loadVotedRatingIds($object->getId()),
            $object->getEntityPkValue()
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Acme_Reviewed_Block_Reviews**

```
<?php

class Acme_Reviewed_Block_Reviews extends Magpleasure_Ajaxreviews_Block_Reviews
{
    public function getTemplateHtml()
    {    
        /** @var Magpleasure_Common_Block_Template $block */
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('magpleasure/template');
        if ($block) {
            return $block->setTemplate('ajaxreviews/product/view/list/template-guest.phtml')->toHtml();
        }
    }
}
```

**Acme/Reviewed/Block/Adminhtml/Review/Edit/Form.php**

```
<?php

class Acme_Reviewed_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $review = Mage::registry('review_data');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getEntityPkValue());
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($review->getCustomerId());
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'), 'ret' => Mage::registry('ret'))),
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('review_details', array('legend' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

        $fieldset->addField('product_name', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Product'),
            'text'      => '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId())) . '" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">' . $product->getName() . '</a>'
        ));

        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('<a href="%1$s" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">%2$s %3$s</a> <a href="mailto:%4$s">(%4$s)</a>', $this->getUrl('*/customer/edit', array('id' => $customer->getId(), 'active_tab'=>'review')), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstname()), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getLastname()), $this->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()));
        } else {
            if (is_null($review->getCustomerId())) {
                $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__($review->getGemail());
            } elseif ($review->getCustomerId() == 0) {
                $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('Administrator');
            }
        }

        $fieldset->addField('customer', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Posted By'),
            'text'      => $customerText,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('summary_rating', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary Rating'),
            'text'      => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_summary')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('detailed_rating', 'note', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Detailed Rating'),
            'required'  => true,
            'text'      => '<div id="rating_detail">'
                           . $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_detailed')->toHtml()
                           . '</div>',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('status_id', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Status'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'status_id',
            'values'    => Mage::helper('review')->getReviewStatusesOptionArray(),
        ));

        /**
         * Check is single store mode
         */
        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $field = $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'multiselect', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Visible In'),
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'stores[]',
                'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(),
            ));
            $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element');
            $field->setRenderer($renderer);
            $review->setSelectStores($review->getStores());
        }
        else {
            $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'hidden', array(
                'name'      => 'stores[]',
                'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
            ));
            $review->setSelectStores(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
        }

        $fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'nickname'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary of Review'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('detail', 'textarea', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'detail',
            'style'     => 'height:24em;',
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setValues($review->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your class files too..

Comment: If you're using cache system, in development mode, I suggest that you clean it.

Comment: do you added <?xml version="1.0"?> at the top of all xml files??

Comment: yes, it is there

Comment: edited with class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this riddle. My code is example how much traps are waiting for unexperienced developer.
I made 3 mistakes.

1. Acme/Reviewed/Block/Adminhtml/Review/Edit/Form.php

Whole code of extended function is taken from core file Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form which I extend. I just added a simple changes. So at the end of function is line:

> return parent::_prepareForm();

But the problem is Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form which I extend also extends other file Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.

So in my file 'parent' means Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form but in the core it stands for return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form

I had to change this line to this and works perfect:

> return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form::_prepareForm();

2. Acme/Reviewed/Model/Resource/Review.php

I wrote config well, but for extending model, not for extending model resource. So when I changed config.xml to the code below it is working well also.

```
<review_resource>
    <rewrite>
        <review>Acme_Reviewed_Model_Resource_Review</resource_review>
    </rewrite>
</review_resource>
```

3. Acme_Reviewed_Block_Reviews

So here I wanted to extend function which was located in Magpleasure_Ajaxreviews_Block_Reviews, but I didn't notice that it is not the end of 'extending chain'. I found that the last file which extends Magpleasure_Ajaxreviews_Block_Reviews is Magpleasure_Ajaxreviews_Block_Placing_Additional so I had to extend this class with my changed function.